# Is there a way to change my review decision?

Tags: support, reviewing

Just now, I clicked on the wrong button in the reopen review queue (I intended to vote for reopening, but instead I clicked "leave closed"). Irresponsible and thoughtless as it may be, this is the first time something like this happened to me. I immediately went back and tried to undo, despite remembering that I never saw an undo or revote option, but naturally couldn't do anything about it.

Is there a way to change my review decision once made?

Answer (score 3):

In general, review decisions cannot be undone per se, i.e., they will stay on record and influence review completion as you made them.
However, most review decisions are also not unilateral and single mistakes are no problem.
Moreover, you can often remedy the consequences:

- Close and reopen votes can be cast independently of review and be retracted.
- Flags can be cast and retracted outside of review.
- Edits can be rolled back and you can almost always edit. Also see: [Hit approve instead of reject on a suggested edit](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3739/7734)
- First-post and late-answer reviews can be completely made up outside of review.

In your case, you can just cast go to the question in question and cast a reopen vote by clicking on the respective button. In that case, the only lasting consequence your mistake has it that it takes one *leave closed* decision less to dequeue the question from the reopen queue.